# Change background color fixed menu when scrolling

Tags: javascript, menu

I want to change the background color fro the fixed menu "Wie zijn wij", " Onze missie, visie en kernwaarden" Etc. So when you scroll down and get to a certain point the background changes color. [Example](https://aserio.nl/dit-is-aserio/)

Here is my code what I have made so far:

```js
function scrollIt(element) {  
  window.scrollTo({
    'behavior': 'smooth',
    'left': 0,
    'top': element.offsetTop
  });
}

const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');

btn[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollIt(sections[0]);
});

btn[1].addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollIt(sections[1]);
});

btn[2].addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollIt(sections[2]);
});

btn[3].addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollIt(sections[3]);
});

btn[4].addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollIt(sections[4]);
});

btn[5].addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollIt(sections[5]);
});

btn[6].addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollIt(sections[6]);
});

var header = document.getElementById("sidenav");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    if (current.length > 0) { 
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

#sidenav {
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.btn{
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 176px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a:hover{
  color: ##9ce728;
}

a:focus {
  background-color: #EAB126
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.active, .btn:hover {
    background-color: #a6a8ad;
    color: #fff;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  line-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;

  &:nth-child(even) {
    background: #eee;
  }

  &:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="sidenav">
      <a class="btn">Wie zijn wij?</a>
        <br>
        <a class="btn">Onze missie, visie en kernwaarden</a>
        <br>
        <a class="btn">Wat zegt onze klant?</a>
        <br>
        <a class="btn">Onze klantcases</a>
        <br>
        <a class="btn">Wat zeggen professionals?</a>
        <br>
        <a class="btn">Nieuwsberichten</a>
        <br>
        <a class="btn">Onze klanten</a>
        <br>
</div>

    <div class="section">Pagina 1</div>
    <div class="section">Pagina 2</div>
    <div class="section">Pagina 3</div>
    <div class="section">Pagina 4</div>
    <div class="section">Pagina 5</div>
    <div class="section">Pagina 6</div>
    <div class="section">Pagina 7</div>
```

Its probably a easy fix for someone thats a master in Javascript but its all new for me.
Can someone tell me how this is done?

Comment: You forgot your codepen!

Comment: Yes i am sorry. I dont know how to add it tried changing to Jsfiddle but also didnt work. Thanks Nick

Comment: @Matt He didn't; he just created his anchor attribute as so: `<https://jsfiddle.net/xkmft4sv/1/>Code</a>`. I have proposed an edit.

Comment: @Pete _\*sigh\*_ Thank you, we can but try, I suppose.

Comment: I tried this "[Code][1]" and the link shows up on the bottom but still does not work!

Comment: @Pete I did this. I hope this is the correct way now

Answer (score 0):

use below js for changing the class which contains diffrent background color. i'm using `jquery` here

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <div class='tmp'> This is a sample div  </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {    
      if (document.body.scrollTop <= 0 ){
          console.log('scrolll');
          $(".tmp").addClass("diffColor");
        }
    });
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  height: 400px;
}

.tmp {
  background: red;
  height: 500px;
}

.diffColor {
  background-color: blue;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! This is not what iam looking for. Check the example I add to my question